# Ran into "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Tensor' and 'list'" when going through dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, resnet

I am replicating ResNet (source: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385).

I ran into the error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Tensor' and 'list'" when trying to go through several different dataset in different sections of my code.

I tried different fixes but none worked: (i) I deleted enumerate cause I worried that using this may cause the problem (ii) I tried to go through dataloader rather than dataset but it didn't work

1st time: When I tried to view images:

```
    for images, _ in train_loader:
        print('images.shape:', images.shape)
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images, nrow=16).permute((1, 2, 0)))
        break
```

2nd/3rd time: when I tried to validate/test the resnet:

```
    with torch.no_grad():
        for j, inputs, labels in enumerate(test_loader, start=0):
            outputs = resnet_models[i](inputs) 
            _, prediction = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
```

You may notice that I didn't run into this error when training  the resnet, and the code is quite similar:

```
for batch, data in enumerate(train_dataloader, start=0): 
    inputs, labels = data
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
```

### Error message (taking the first error as an example. The rest is pretty much the same)

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [38], in <cell line: 8>()
> 6 print("Images AFTER NORMALIZATION")
> 7 print("--------------------------")
> ----> 8 for images, _ in training_data:
> 9     sort=False
> 10     print('images.shape:', images.shape)
>
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/resnet/lib/python3.9/site->packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py:471, in Subset.**getitem**(self, idx)
> 469 if isinstance(idx, list):
> 470     return self.dataset[[self.indices[i] for i in idx]]
> --> 471 return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]
>
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/resnet/lib/python3.9/site->packages/torchvision/datasets/cifar.py:118, in CIFAR10.**getitem**(self, index)
> 115 img = Image.fromarray(img)
> 117 if self.transform is not None:
> --> 118     img = self.transform(img)
> 120 if self.target_transform is not None:
> 121     target = self.target_transform(target)
>
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/resnet/lib/python3.9/site->packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py:95, in Compose.**call**(self, img)
> 93 def **call**(self, img):
> 94     for t in self.transforms:
> ---> 95         img = t(img)
> 96     return img
>
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/resnet/lib/python3.9/site->packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1110, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
> 1106 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
> 1107 # this function, and just call forward.
> 1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks >or _global_backward_hooks
> 1109         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
> -> 1110     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
> 1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used
> 1112 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []
>
> File ~/miniconda3/envs/resnet/lib/python3.9/site->packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py:707, in RandomHorizontalFlip.forward(self, >img)
> 699 def forward(self, img):
> 700     """
> 701     Args:
> 702         img (PIL Image or Tensor): Image to be flipped.
> (...)
> 705         PIL Image or Tensor: Randomly flipped image.
> 706     """
> --> 707     if torch.rand(1) < self.p:
> 708         return F.hflip(img)
> 709     return img
>
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Tensor' and 'list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same error message, probably under different circumstances, but I just found my own bug and figured I would share it anyway for various readers. I was using a torchvision transformation in my dataset, which the dataloader was loading from. The transformation was

torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip([0.5]),

and the error is that the input to this transformation should not be a list but should be

torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5),

So if there is anything I can recommend, it's just that maybe there is some list argument being passed through that shouldn't be in some transformation or otherwise.